# Find multiple names inside of block of text in word and copy the block of text

Tags: vba, ms-word

Every time the code found that word it would copy and paste text between a start and end position onto another sheet and roll to the next extract until it reached the end of the raw written extracts.

example would be

```
Start
Susan Had a lovely day today and made a lekker poo
end

Start1
John was feeling siiiccckkk so he took a poo too
end1

start2
Peter was in lots of trouble, so he bailed bro
end2

start3
Jacobus rektus van nel het n bal wat hy hey spiel met sy pieletjie
ending3
```

The desired outcome would be to find all extracts the words (Susan,Jacobus,Peter) and to copy them from "Start" to "End" as in the code and paste them one below the other in a new workbook.Thus John would not be included as I did not want to use him in my list of names.

The code is case sensitive, Could someone please help me create this list function, my attempt is below with NameToHighlight = Array("JASON", "JAMES ") , but the code is only returning the Jason extracts.

```
Sub CopyMsg_JarrydWard()
    Dim DocA As Document
    Dim DocB As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Set DocA = ThisDocument
    Set DocB = Documents.Add

    Dim Rg As Range, RgMsg As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String, NameToHighlight As Variant
    Dim FoundName As Boolean
    Set Rg = DocA.Content
    Rg.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rg.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    StartWord = "Start Message"
    EndWord = "End Message"
    'NameToHighlight = "DUNCAN HOWES"
'NameToHighlight = "DUNCAN HOWES,cat,pig,horse,man"
NameToHighlight = Array("JASON", "JAMES ") ' list of words in here

For i = LBound(NameToHighlight) To UBound(NameToHighlight)
    With Rg.Find
        'Set the parameters for your Find method
        .Text = StartWord & "*" & EndWord
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        'Execute the Find
        .Execute
        'Loop through the results
        While .Found
            'Boolean to copy only message containing NameToHighlight
            FoundName = False
            'Keep Rg (result range for whole message) intact for later copy
            Set RgMsg = Rg.Duplicate

            'Highlight
            'Start and End
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.Start, End:=Rg.Start + Len(StartWord)).Bold = True
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.End - Len(EndWord), End:=Rg.End).Bold = True
            'NameToHighlight : here : Susan
            With RgMsg.Find
                'Set the parameters for your Find method
                .Text = NameToHighlight(i)
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                'Execute the Find
                .Execute
                'Loop through the results
                While .Found
                    RgMsg.Bold = True
                    FoundName = True
                    'Go to the next result for NameToHighlight
                    .Execute
                Wend
            End With 'RgMsg.Find

            'Copy the whole message if NameToHighlight was found
            If FoundName Then
                Rg.Copy
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = "Page " & _
                        Rg.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Paste
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = vbCr & vbCr
            End If
            'Go to the next result for the message
            .Execute
        Wend
    End With 'Rg.Find
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but you need to wrap the `Find` for the names only :

```
Sub CopyMsg_JarrydWard()
    Dim DocA As Document
    Dim DocB As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Set DocA = ThisDocument
    Set DocB = Documents.Add

    Dim Rg As Range, RgMsg As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String, NameToHighlight As Variant
    Dim FoundName As Boolean
    Set Rg = DocA.Content
    Rg.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rg.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    StartWord = "Start Message"
    EndWord = "End Message"
    'NameToHighlight = "DUNCAN HOWES"
'NameToHighlight = "DUNCAN HOWES,cat,pig,horse,man"
NameToHighlight = Array("JASON", "JAMES ") ' list of words in here

    With Rg.Find
        'Set the parameters for your Find method
        .Text = StartWord & "*" & EndWord
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        'Execute the Find
        .Execute
        'Loop through the results
        While .Found
            'Boolean to copy only message containing NameToHighlight
            FoundName = False
            'Keep Rg (result range for whole message) intact for later copy
            Set RgMsg = Rg.Duplicate

            'Highlight
            'Start and End
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.Start, End:=Rg.Start + Len(StartWord)).Bold = True
            DocA.Range(Start:=Rg.End - Len(EndWord), End:=Rg.End).Bold = True

            For i = LBound(NameToHighlight) To UBound(NameToHighlight)
                'NameToHighlight : here : Susan
                With RgMsg.Find
                    'Set the parameters for your Find method
                    .Text = NameToHighlight(i)
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Format = False
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    'Execute the Find
                    .Execute
                    'Loop through the results
                    While .Found
                        RgMsg.Bold = True
                        FoundName = True
                        'Go to the next result for NameToHighlight
                        .Execute
                    Wend
                End With 'RgMsg.Find
            Next i
            'Copy the whole message if NameToHighlight was found
            If FoundName Then
                Rg.Copy
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = "Page " & _
                        Rg.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Paste
                DocB.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Text = vbCr & vbCr
            End If
            'Go to the next result for the message
            .Execute
        Wend
    End With 'Rg.Find
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank so much Bud, I do feel bad for being hostile earlier on...Your code writing skills are very advance and I am very appreciative of your help, I hope you have a super weekend, again thanks so much.

Comment: @JarrydWard : Don't worry, just don't let it happen again! ;) Have a nice week-end too! ;)